# bash create a variable using two variables with a whitespace between them?

Tags: bash, whitespace

I'm trying to create a a variable using two variables with a whitespace between them. I want to use this new variable to create a folder. The problem is that with the whitespace, it gets interpeted as a speration of the variable and creates two folder, one with the first var and another with the second! Is there any way to make bash consider that it is as whitespace?

```
my_array=($(echo $dataString | tr ":" "\n"))
for i in "${my_array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
echo

year=${my_array[2]}
month=${my_array[3]}
day=${my_array[4]}
hour=${my_array[5]}
min=${my_array[6]}`

year_month="$year $month"

if [ -d "$year_month" ]; then
    echo "$year_month exists"
else 
    mkdir $year_month
    echo "$year_month created"
fi
```

Comment: Put $year_month in quotes and so mkdir "$year_month"

Comment: I can't believe it's so simple!!! I've been searching for an answer for two days! thank you so very much ;-) I really feel so dumb right now.

Comment: use `mkdir -p "$year_month"` which will not complain about existing directories.